# SSMS 2008 not remembering connection login credentials

Tags: passwords, ssms

When connecting to a server on SQL Server Management Studio 2008, I'm entering the `Server Name`, and using `SQL Server Authentication`, entering `Login` & `Password`, and ticking `Remember password`.

However, next time I open SSMS, the server name has been remembered in the drop down, but the login and password have been forgotten.

Why is this?

Comment: This question has been answered on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/287099/ssms-2008-not-remembering-connection-login-credentials/